# How To Store Array Variable In Select Query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I wanted to know how I can store an array variable into a select query, and if its okay to have the following inside a while loop. Thanks in advance.

For example:

```
$roww = array();
while ($roww = $resultt->fetch_assoc()) { 

$uery = $dbconn->prepare("SELECT user_ids FROM t_friendship WHERE friend_ids = $roww['id'] AND status = 'Pending'");
$uery->execute();
$uery->store_result();

$rows = $uery->num_rows;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use curly braces around the array variable like this `{$roww['id']}`

Also you could construct a string of `ids` like `('1','2','3')` inside the while loop and in one `SELECT` outside the `while` you can use `IN` of `MySQL` to select the results.

Comment: All The Other Answers Worked Out But Your Was The Most Simple Thanks Man

Comment: @TonyThinkk No worries!!

Answer (score 0):

Another alternatives for **curly brackets** would be use of **double quotes** then a concatenate it.

```
$query = $dbconn->prepare("SELECT user_ids FROM t_friendship WHERE friend_ids = ".$roww['id']." AND status = 'Pending'");
```

Answer (score 0):

// Now mysql result set is stored in php variable.

```
$result = mysql_query($querystring, $dbconn)

$array = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
{
    $array[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use within single quotes

```
    $uery = $dbconn->prepare("SELECT user_ids FROM t_friendship WHERE friend_ids = '".$roww['id']."' AND status = 'Pending'");
    $uery->execute();
```

first check out `id` value just `echo $roww['id']`. If you getting that value means use above the code